# error TS2347: Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash

I have my `bar.ts` as follows:

```
declare var angular:any;
declare var _:any;
declare var $:any;
declare var moment:any;
declare var ng:any;
declare var require:any;
```

my bootstrap.ts as follows:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="bar.ts" />
.............
```

But when I'm using _ as following

```
this.csSubtitle = _.get<string>(_.find(this.csRadios, { value: this.csRadioValue }), 'label');
```

it throws following error:

error TS2347: Untyped function calls may not accept type argument

Comment: Can you remove `<string>` from that line?  Why are you declaring all those values as `any` types?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happened is because you were probably trying to fetch type information in the presence of an import directive, so using require on its own isn't sufficient in this case.

So let's say you have

```
var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;
```

Replace it with:

```
import es6PromiseLib = require('es6-promise');
var Promise = es6PromiseLib.Promise;
```

Generally you use type arguments if you want to have type safety. So that's a good thing you specify it.